# Producing a list of keywords

Tags: glossaries, automation

I made a lot of worksheets for my students. I'd like to help them out by having a list of keywords at the top of my worksheet. I would like to automate the generation of this list by flagging a term within the body of the document. Does anyone have any suggestions for packages that could help me out?

Comment: Besides the glossaries package?

Comment: @JohnKormylo My understanding of the glossaries package is that you have to declare all your terms in the preamble. I would rather do it in the body.

Comment: Looks like you want an index, maybe https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Indexing can help you?